# Unable to properly override keyPressed(KeyEvent) in java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to create a keylistener that detects when the user hits the 'enter' key, but every time I compile it, I get the error:

```
 NameBox.java:6: error: NameBox is not abstract and does not override 
 abstract method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
 public class NameBox extends JFrame implements KeyListener
        ^
```

In my class provided below, I was sure I properly implemented the correct key listeners but clearly I haven't. If anybody could shed some light as to why I am still getting this error, that would be fantastic!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NameBox extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    String userWord = "";
    JTextField userInput = new JTextField(20);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

    public NameBox()
    {
        super("Enter your name");
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        setSize(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        submit.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
            {
                if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    submitAction();
                }
            }
        });
        centerPanel.add(userInput);
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        southPanel.add(submit);
        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        theBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
        theBox.add(centerPanel);
        theBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(200));
        theBox.add(southPanel);
        add(theBox);

    }
    private void submitAction()
    {
        userWord = userInput.getText();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new NameBox().setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

}
```

Comment: The error is self evident, you've promised to implement the contract specified by the `KeyListener` interface, but have failed to provide the implementation - instead, for some weird reason, you've added a `KeyListener` to the button, instead of using an `ActionListener` for which it was designed

Comment: I strongly recommend that you have a look at [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to write an action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and, if for some strange reason, you still need to monitor key events, [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as `KeyListener` is just a paint in the ... code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the `keyTyped` and `keyReleased` methods, but the `KeyListener` interface requires that you also include the `keyPressed` method, even if it is blank like the others.  To fix this, you could add `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that you had to still override keyPressed even if you were using it within your class!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Lambda expression, its super easy and simply in your case.

```
userInput.addActionListener(e -> submitAction());
```

Lambda expressions can completely rid your inner ActionListener class.
I'm not sure why, but the default Action for a TextField is to listen for an "enter" key.

Also if you want to keep your ActionListener, you **MUST** override the other methods for a keylistener, even if the action has an empty definition.

```
        /**
         * to keep compiler happy
         */
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {}
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){}
```